# reducing bpp of an image using Scilab

Tags: image-processing, scilab

Hi guys,

I'm trying to reduce the number of bits per pixel to below 8, on gray scale images using Scilab

- Is this possible?
- If so, how can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What toolbox are you using? SIVP?

Comment: Yes. SIVP , Image Processing Design and Image_Processing_Tool_3. all of them

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. The integer types available in Scilab are one or multiple bytes, see types [here](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/int8.html).

If you are looking to loose the high frequency information, you could shift out information.

### Pseudo implementation

```
for x=1:width
    for y=1:height

        // Get pixel and make a 1 byte integer  
        pixel = int8(picture(x,y))

        //Display bits
        disp( dec2bin(pixel) )

        // We start out with 8 bits - 4 = 4 bits info
        bits_to_shift = 4
        shifted_down_pixel = pixel/(2^bits_to_shift)

        //Display shifted down
        disp( dec2bin(shifted_down_pixel))

        //Shift it back
        shifted_back_pixel = pixel*(2^bits_to_shift)
        disp( dec2bin(shifted_back_pixel))

        // Replace old pixel with new
        picture(x,y)  = shifted_back_pixel
    end     
end
```

Of course you can do the above code much faster with one big matrix operation, but it is to show the concept.

### Working example

```
rgb = imread('your_image.png')

gry = rgb2gray(rgb)
gry8bit = im2uint8(gry)

function result = reduce_bits(img, bits)    
    reduced = img / (2^bits);
    result = reduced * (2^bits);
    return result;
endfunction

gry2bit = reduce_bits(gry8bit, 6)
imshow(gry2bit)
```